# Android Bootloader Debugging

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-emulator, bootloader, kgdb

I am trying to debug `aboot` (aplication bootloader) on android and I have problems. I tried to patch the kernel to support `KGDB` serial debugging but the driver is loaded after aboot. Should I use an emulator? And if yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

aboot is HW platform dependent and normally is cryptographically signed.   Emulator's aboot if exists will be a lot different than the real device.

You can probably debug it with vendor supplied ICE plus their special debug scripts.

Comment: Can you please suggest me from where to download Samsung's aboot debug scripts?

Comment: And btw , sorry for being a n00b but what does ICE mean?

Comment: `ICE` stands for `In-circuit emulator`. But @Y_Yen has probably meant `ICD` (In-circuit debugger)